# what the "increment" part of for loop in solidity does?

Tags: loops, for-loop, ethereum, blockchain, solidity

As I've been searching, this is the syntax of "for loop" in Solidity:

```
for (initialization; condition; increment) {
           statement or block of code to be executed if the condition is True
}
```

But I couldn't understand what does the "increment" part do exactly.
And also what is the difference between this part ("increment" part) and the part we set what the loop does in curly brackets(I mean these "{}"}

this sounds a very basic question but I'm new at programming!

Answer (score 0):

The increment part of a for-loop executes at the end of a loop and increments your initialization.

The common for loop in many languages looks like this:

```
for(uint256 i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    // do something with `i`
}
```

We initialize variable `i` with value `0` and at the end of the loop we check the condition (`i < 10`) and run the increment code `i++` to increment `i` by 1 and then we loop again.

There are also `while` loops that you might want to look up for your own knowledge. Because in a `while` loop we have to manually increment the initializer in between the curly brackets.

Answer (score 0):

In Solidity, the "for" loop follows the general structure you provided:

```
for (initialization; condition; increment) {
    // statement or block of code to be executed if the condition is True
}
```

Breaking down each part of the "for" loop with discussion of its role using different scenarios for better understanding:

1. **Initialization:**

   - This part is executed only once at the beginning of the loop.
   - It typically initializes a variable that will be used as a counter or for some other purpose.

   ```
   for (uint i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
       // code here
   }
   ```

   Here, `uint i = 0` initializes a counter variable `i` with an initial value of 0.
2. **Condition:**

   - The loop continues executing as long as this condition is true.
   - If the condition becomes false, the loop terminates.

   ```
   for (uint i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
       // code here
   }
   ```

   In this example, the loop will continue as long as `i` is less than 5.
3. **Increment:**

   - This part is executed after each iteration of the loop.
   - It typically increments or updates the loop control variable.

   ```
   for (uint i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
       // code here
   }
   ```

   The `i++` part increments the value of `i` by 1 after each iteration.

Now, let's consider a scenario to understand the role of the increment part:

```
for (uint i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    // code here
}
```

Suppose you want to print the values of `i` in each iteration. Without the increment part (`i++`), the loop would run indefinitely, as `i` would always remain 0, and the condition `i < 5` would never be false. The increment part ensures that `i` increases with each iteration, eventually causing the condition to be false and terminating the loop.

Regarding the part inside the curly brackets `{}`, that is the block of code that gets executed in each iteration if the condition is true. It's where you define what the loop should do. For example:

```
for (uint i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    // code here
    // This block of code is executed in each iteration
}
```

This block can contain any valid Solidity code, and it's what determines the actions performed during each iteration of the loop.

In essence, the "increment" part is responsible for updating the loop control variable, and the code inside the curly brackets defines what the loop does in each iteration. Together, these parts allow you to create flexible and controlled loops in Solidity. I hope this detailed explanation on `for loop` is well understood.

Comment: Thank you so much for your clear explanation.I got that all differently.

Comment: Awesome. You welcome